# Sticky CTA Bottom Button Only On Mobile to Wordpress Website All Pages

Tags: wordpress, button, call

I am planning to add a button which will be sticked to bottom of the screen, centered, only on mobile to my wordpress web site but ı must to insert this button to all pages on my website. I don't want it to show on desktop or any other devices.

Can someone help me about this.Because ıdont want call now button plugin.I want to use this without plugin.

All help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add button HTML with class name in a widget and call widget code in the footer. Then you can add a media query to button class to display in mobile.

Comment: Can you give me a example please?